# Icomoon Submit button

Tags: php, html, submit, webfonts

I've started using Icomoon on a page I'm creating and would like to use the font as a value to display on the button, but it seems the only way to present the font on the page is through a span.

`<span class='icon-heart'></span>`

Is there a way to create a submit button using this span? I'd like to create this so i can then use an isset in php!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<button type="submit"><span class="icon-heart></span> Heart</button>
```